# How to set the width of ag grid container to auto size?

Tags: reactjs, ag-grid, ag-grid-react

I am using ag grid 27 community version in a react typescript application.I am wondering how to set the total width to something like 'auto'. Like when there are fewer columns and on larger screens the container should occupy only that much width and not 100% width. Also on smaller screens with an overflowX auto.

I used these styles for the wrapper div

```
const gridStyle = useMemo(() => ({ height: '100%', width: 'auto', overflowX: 'auto' }), []);
```

and jsx looks like

```
<div style={gridStyle} className="ag-theme-alpine">
    <AgGridReact rowData={rowData} columnDefs={columnDefs} />
</div>
```

But no success!Tried a basic table here https://plnkr.co/edit/xKxE6OktkUR4OStF

I am trying to do is to avoid the extra vacant space to the right when the screen is large or not enough columns to show. In the case of smaller screens horizontal scroll is fine.
[image]

Comment: https://www.ag-grid.com/react-data-grid/column-sizing/ `flex:1` is what you are looking for.

Comment: I have given you the answer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77064313/how-to-set-the-width-of-ag-grid-container-to-auto-size/77071648#77071648

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> We can set a max width for the first two columns and then expand the
> last column to fill the remaining space

This is our method that we call on a button click (Size to Fit)

```
const sizeToFit = useCallback(() => {
  if (gridRef)
    gridRef.current.api.sizeColumnsToFit()
}, [gridRef])
```

Here's our column definitions

```
const [columnDefs, setColumnDefs] = useState<ColDef[]>([
  {
    field: 'name',
    maxWidth: 150,
    suppressSizeToFit: true, // we do not want this field to be included in the auto resize process
    cellStyle: (params) => {
      return { backgroundColor: params.data?.bg || 'transparent' };
    },
  },
  { field: 'medals.gold', headerName: 'Gold', maxWidth: 75, suppressSizeToFit: true },
  { field: 'person.age' },
]);
```

**Result**

[image: Result]

Working plunker: https://plnkr.co/edit/e8ovhaUzUFGG0S9S?preview

Further reading: https://www.ag-grid.com/react-data-grid/column-sizing/

**NOTE:** If you want the grid to be automatically resized, just pass onGridReady prop to the AgGridReact component like that

```
onGridReady={sizeToFit}
```

Answer (score 2):

In your code, you use `maxWidth` for every columns in `columnDefs`. That's why all columns's width are not as expected.

You can use `flex: 1` in `columnDefs` for specific columns.

```js
columnDefs: [
{
  headerName: 'SN',
  field: 'sn',
  flex: 1
},.....
]
```

But note that `flex` doesn't work with `width`. You can only combine `flex` with `maxWidh` and `minWidth`.

My favorite config is set `flex:1` in defaultColDef to apply for all column and custom minWidth/maxWidth for each columns.

```js
const defaultColDef = useMemo(() => {
  return {
    wrapHeaderText: true,
    resizable: true,
    sortable: true,
    filters: true,
    flex: 1,
  };
}, []);

columnDefs: [{
    headerName: 'SN',
    field: 'sn',
    minWidth: 80,
    maxWidth: 90,
  },
  {
    headerName: 'Sub-trade',
    field: 'subTrade',
    minWidth: isHdScreen ? 70 : 90
  },

  .....
]
```

This [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/77064479/21831091) gave references for this.
And remember to pass props to ag-grid

```js
<div style={gridStyle} className="ag-theme-alpine">
    <AgGridReact rowData={rowData} columnDefs={columnDefs} defaultColDef={defaultColDef} />
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

For this scenario, AG Grid provides 'minWidth' and 'maxWidth' properties under column sizing section. I am attaching link for your reference:
https://www.ag-grid.com/react-data-grid/column-properties/#reference-width-minWidth

Comment: Does setting the width property to columns affect column-wise and not the wrapper div? I have tried it here https://plnkr.co/edit/xKxE6OktkUR4OStF

Comment: @user, you can follow this guide as well:
[https://www.ag-grid.com/react-data-grid/column-sizing/#resizing-columns-when-data-is-rendered](https://www.ag-grid.com/react-data-grid/column-sizing/#resizing-columns-when-data-is-rendered)